# Linked Blend File growing very large

Tags: linked-data

We have a master file which links to other files scene files, characters, etc. The file started at 1.5 Gb last week and is now at 14 Gb. The only thing changed in the master file is animation. No new meshes, textures, etc. Every day we save the file it grows by GB. Maybe there is something I am doing wrong?

[image: Image Showing File Size getting Larger]

Is there anyone using linked files successfully that can help?

Comment: have you tried *File > Clean Up >*

Comment: Yes, did that. Actually after i deleted some skeletal armatures and cleaned up the file, it grew by another 1.5 Gb. All i did was delete. The file should be smaller not bigger.